# I am trying to fetch data kept in a table's column with datatype <XMLTYPE>. I have to get all field names with values using procedure/ query

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

```
    <record>
      <field>
        <fieldName>employee id</fieldName>
        <fieldValue>2000001</fieldValue>
      </field>
      <field>
        <fieldName>employee name</fieldName>
        <fieldValue>pankaj kumar</fieldValue>
      </field>
    </record>
```

The data extracted should be like this:

employee id |   employee name
2000001     |   pankaj kumar

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE houses(
  HOUSE_ID NUMBER(4),
  house_add XMLTYPE,
  HOUSE_NAME VARCHAR2(35)
  );
```

Inserting the value in the table;

```
 INSERT INTO houses VALUES 
   (100, XMLType('<house whNo="100"> 
               <Building>Owned</Building>
               </house>'), 'housename1');
```

To fech :-

```
SELECT house_add  FROM HOUSES W;
```

`o/p`:-`<house whNo="100">      <BUILDING>OWNED</BUILDING>       </house>`

To fetch Building detail:-

```
SELECT  
  w.house_add.extract('/house/Building/text()').getStringVal()     "Building"
  FROM HOUSES W;
```

`o/p`:-Owned

For your case:-

```
WITH T AS
(select xmltype('<?xml version = "1.0"?>
  <record>
      <FIELD>
       <Field Name="employee id"  fieldValue="2000001"/>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD>
       <Field Name="employee name"  fieldValue="pankajkumar"/>
      </FIELD>
    </record>
') XML FROM DUAL
)
SELECT  Y.NAME, Y.VALUE
FROM T     ,
                       XMLTABLE('/record/FIELD/Field'
              PASSING T.XML
               COLUMNS NAME VARCHAR2(20) PATH '@Name',
                 VALUE VARCHAR2(20) PATH '@fieldValue'  
               )Y
```

output:-

```
NAme             Value

employee id      2000001
employee name   pankajkumar
```

This will help you !!

Comment: I am using this as <SELECT  
  w.house_add.extract('/house/Building/text()').getStringVal()  FROM HOUSES W;> and I am getting the desired result. BUt in my case, there are multiple field names and fieldvalues. Which all get concatanated in result set. How to get each fieldname and field value separately.